# Accessing my external drive connected to my Belkin router over the Internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a Belkin n900 wifi router and I connected my Verbatim External SSD to it and I can access it on the local network, that is I can browse and download my files, I would like to access my drive through SSH over the internet so that when I am at school I don't need to rely on companies holding my data in there servers, and I can access it. I just want to keep it at home. Is there some way I can make this happen?

Comment: Don't do it with FTP. FTP is totally insecure.

Comment: Enable SSH access to the disk in the router's control interface, and access the data using SFTP.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy In the Belkin's configuration it has virtual servers , so would I have to open a port for SSH and input an ip address for the external usb drive connected to my router.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I will not use FTP I'll try SSH.